# Testing load of a highchart using python and selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xpath, waits

I am writing a program that must screen some charts, the issue is that I do not know how much time a graph expends to load, it could be seconds or minutes.
How can I make an appropriate wait, that only continues executing whenever the chart is fully loaded?
I have thought about waiting for the load event, but I am not sure how to approach that.

Comment: Can you give some code examples of the charts and what you tried? You probably gonna need to simply make an explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a chart to be fully loaded before continuing with your program, you can use techniques like polling or waiting for specific events. Here's an approach using JavaScript and the load event to wait for a chart to be fully loaded:

**Add an Event Listener:** You can add an event listener to the chart element to listen for the load event. This event is triggered when the chart is fully loaded and ready for interaction.

Assuming you have a chart element with an id attribute like this:

```
<div id="chart"> <!-- Your chart content here --> </div>
```

You can add an event listener in your JavaScript code as follows:

```
const chartElement = document.getElementById('chart');

chartElement.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // This code will be executed when the chart is fully loaded.
    // You can continue with your program here.
});
```

**Polling Approach:** If the chart doesn't have a built-in load event, you can use a polling approach to continuously check whether the chart is loaded. You can use setInterval to check the chart's status at regular intervals until it's fully loaded. Here's an example:

```
function checkChartLoaded() {
    const chartElement = document.getElementById('chart');
    
    if (chartElement.complete) {
        // The chart is fully loaded.
        // You can continue with your program here.
    } else {
        // The chart is not fully loaded yet.
        // You can set the polling interval to your desired value (e.g., 1000ms).
        setTimeout(checkChartLoaded, 1000);
    }
}

// Start the polling process
checkChartLoaded();
```

This code will keep checking whether the chart is fully loaded at 1-second intervals. Once it's fully loaded, it will continue with your program.